# shell script to read a file line by line in unix and update the line in the file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a log file written by the java code like below .

```
<date>|<command>|<Error>
<date>|<command>|<Error>
<date>|<command>|<Error>
<date>|<command>|<Error>
```

I need to write a script to loop in line by line from the line and execute the command and update the status = "Processed" on the line in the same file .

```
 AutoTrigger()
{

echo "`date`: Checking the status of the files . Please wait..."

if [[ -s /tmp/samplefilelog.log ]] ; then

cat /tmp/samplefilelog.log | while read LINE
do
echo "LINE:" $LINE
LINE1=`echo $LINE |  grep -v Processed`
echo "LINE1:" $LINE1
Command=`echo $LINE1 | cut -d "|" -f3`
echo "command:" $Command
$Command >> /tmp/Processinglogs.txt
printf $LINE | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$4="Processed";print}'

cat /tmp/samplefilelog.log
done
fi

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the old value of `<status>` before you change it to `Processed`? Unless it is at least as long as the new status (e.g. `Unprocessed`), you can't do the change in situ; the longer status would overwrite the material on the next line of the file. Plus, it is very difficult to read a line, seek back a line, and write a line in shell. So, your outline approach writing to 'same file' is essentially fatally flawed in shell. It would be tricky in C or a similar language; it could be done if the length condition is met, but it probably isn't a good idea. You should copy the info to a new file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: <date>|<command>|<Error>                                                                                <date>|<command>|<Error>                                                                            <date>|<command>|<Error>                                                                             Here i need to read the line by line                                                                 get the command and execute                                                                    update the Error - Processed in the same log file .

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{ OFS="|"}{
  if ($3 ~ "Error"){
    system($2);
    $3="Processed";
  }
  print $0 > "/tmp/logfile.new";
}' logfile
mv /tmp/logfile.new logfile
```

- `system()` of `awk` will execute the command which is the second
  field (seperated by `|`) if third field has "Error" in status.
- Then third field is marked as "Processed".
- The last line with `mv` command moves the new file created to the
  original input file.
- As pointed out in comments to my post, it should be noted that output of `system()` will be printed on the console and the modified contents of the file will be redirected to the file.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the redirection in the `print` statement means that the standard output of the commands executed by `system` go to the standard output (of `awk`) — which is why you don't do shell-level redirection of the output log file.  That's a subtle point which you did well to code for, but should call out.  You should probably also state that you can't/don't modify the file in situ.

Comment: I need loop in the file line by line and i have to execute a command and the replace the <Error> status to <Processed> . My doubt here is how can we replace the string line by line one by one in the looop .

Comment: `awk` command shown in my post reads the file line by line and executes command using `system()` call and then changes the third field to "Processsed".

Comment: Will the Processed line will replace my existing line which is being "Processed" or will it create another line(duplicate line) in the original logfile ? ..

Comment: It will replace the existing line if you run the whole script. You can try running the script to see how it works and if it does not suit you, let us know what was missing from your expectation.

Comment: Thanks. Yes - I would need to process only those lines which has Status = Error & not the Processed ones . Can you please include the condition inside this loop .

Comment: Made the changes. Hopefully this is what you require!!

Comment: Yea thanks. Further - the system($2) is not working .. i tried to keep the parameter like below to execute my own script .this will the actual scenario as well .                                              1|/proj/tas01l/ua/Automated_Payment_Transfer_Trigger.sh|Error

Comment: Try `1|bash /proj/tas01l/ua/Automated_Payment_Transfer_Trigger.sh|Erro‌​r`

Comment: No , its not working - even tried this - system("bash -c '\''" $2 "'\''") .. Could u please suggest